# Web scraping using R's rvest package and RSelenium

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, html-table

I usually have no problem scraping html tables using the `read_html` command from `rvest` however, I'm having some trouble with a particular website. Any help would be much appreciated. Here's my workflow:

```
#Dependencies
library(rvest)
library(pipeR)

#Scrape table from site
url2 <- "http://priceonomics.com/hotels/rankings/#airbnb-apartments-all"
data2 <- url2 %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="airbnb-apartments-all"]/table') %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
data2<-data2[[1]]
```

What I end up with is a table with the correct column headings but no data! I would like to scrape the 2nd table on that site.

```
data2
[1] Rank City $        
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I used google chrome to identify the xpath. I've also tried the following:

```
readHTMLTable(url2)
```

Which produces:

```
$`NULL`
NULL

$`NULL`
NULL

$`NULL`
NULL
```

Finally, in case the website is using Java, I tried using R's `RSelenium` package, but I can't seem to connect to the server properly:

```
library(RSelenium)
checkForServer()
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName="firefox", port=4444)
remDr$open(silent=T)
Undefined error in RCurl call.Error in queryRD(paste0(serverURL, "/session"), "POST", qdata = toJSON(serverOpts)) :
```

Comment: I'd advise ... NOT ... destructively  assigning to data2 ... but rather assigning to a different name. Look at `data2 <- url2 %>%   read_html() `

Comment: Thank you or the suggestion but I'm not sure I follow, are you suggesting I simply change the name of "data2"?

Comment: When you make a destructive assignment, you cannot then look back at the intermediate results.

Comment: So how do you suggest I change the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the data is returned in a `JSON` file. You can probably construct the tables with it. For example the first table:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(data.table)
appData <- fromJSON("http://priceonomics.com/static/js/hotels/all_data.json")
# replicate table
myDf <- data.frame(City = names(appData), Price = sapply(appData, function(x) x$air$apt$p)
                   , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
setDT(myDf)
> myDf[order(Price, decreasing = TRUE)][1:10]
City Price
1:        Boston, MA 185.0
2:      New York, NY 180.0
3: San Francisco, CA 165.0
4:     Cambridge, MA 155.0
5:    Scottsdale, AZ 142.5
6:     Charlotte, NC 139.5
7:    Charleston, SC 139.5
8:     Las Vegas, NV 135.0
9:         Miami, FL 135.0
10:       Chicago, IL 130.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the response above @jdharrison. I was also ultimately successful with the Selenium approach. Here's my workflow:

```
#Load dependencies
devtools::install_github("ropensci/RSelenium", force=T)
library(RSelenium)

#Access Chrome driver
checkForServer(update=T)
startServer(javaargs="/users/name/folder/chromedriver") #path to where chromedriver is located on local hard (downloaded from: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome") 
remDr$open()

#Navigate to url, read, and sparse html table into dataframe
remDr$navigate("http://priceonomics.com/hotels/rankings/#airbnb-apartments-all")
doc <- htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
doc<-readHTMLTable(doc)
data2<-doc[[2]]
```